# В чём проблема?

Tags: java, javafx

В классе `ControllerMainManu`:

```
if (ChoiceRe.getText() == "Обычный") {
    System.out.println("Обычный режим запущен");
    TimeStart = Integer.toString(normalTime);
    try {
        x = new Formatter("src//application//res//Re//TemporaryTimeStart.txt");
        x.format(TimeStart);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    x.close();
    WindowNormalReTimer windowNormalReTimer = new WindowNormalReTimer(HelperTime);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(windowNormalReTimer);
    time.progressProperty().bind(progress);
    t1.start();
    Indicator i = new Indicator();
    i.j(null);
}
```

В классе `Indicator`:

```
public class Indicator extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    ProgressIndicator progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator(0);

      Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            double TimeStart = 0d;
            for (int row = 0; row < 100; row++) {
                TimeStart = TimeStart + 0.01;
                updateProgress(TimeStart, 1);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(27);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
      };
      progressIndicator.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());

      Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit(task);

      Scene scene = new Scene(progressIndicator);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
  }

  public static void j(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }


}
```

Вот ошибка:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source) at
javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source) at
javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source) at
javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source) at
javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source) at
javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source) at
javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source) at
javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source) at
javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source) at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method) at
com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/2075313.run(Unknown Source) at
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source) at
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source) at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source) 
... 48 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application launch must not be called more than once at
com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source) at
javafx.application.Application.launch(Unknown Source) at
application.Indicator.j(Indicator.java:44) at
application.ControllerMainMenu.start(ControllerMainMenu.java:280) ... 57 more
```

Comment: А как эти классы между собой связаны?

Answer (score 2):

Согласно [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String...-) к методу `launch()`:

> Launch a standalone application. This method is typically called from
>   the main method(). It must not be called more than once or an
>   exception will be thrown.

Как видим, данный метод нельзя вызывать более одного раза иначе будет выкинуто исключение, что и происходит в вашем случае.